# Problem to connect on MySql database on the remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I have been developing my php mysql application locally and it worked fine with this connection parameters:

```
    // Database connection params
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('DATABASE', 'some_db');
```

at some point I wanted to put application online with connection parameters:

```
define('HOST', 'somedomain.com');
define('USERNAME', 'some_db_admin');
define('PASSWORD', 'Password1!');
define('DATABASE', 'some_db');
```

When I try to connect to remote database like this:

```
function db_connect()
{
    $connection = @mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
    if(!$connection)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!mysql_select_db(DATABASE))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $connection;
}
```

I get error:
Access denied for user 'some_db'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How can it possibly be localhost?

I have regularly created database and user that database using using database wizard in cpanel.

What can be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP code is at the same host where the MySQL database is then setting HOST to localhost should solve your problem

define('HOST', 'localhost');

Comment: I believe his db is on a "remote server"

Comment: why did this answer got a -1 ? if the php and the mysql are in the same place then setting HOST to localhost works just fine

Comment: Right, but since he mentioned he was developing locally and everything was fine, and then moved the application online, I guessed he might have just put everything in the same server (both the php and the database). I dont see a reason for a -1 , was only trying to help.

Comment: How do you mean the same server?

Comment: The same server hosting both the PHP and the MySQl. Or is that you have your php hosted in one place, and your MySQL hosted in another one?

Comment: I get your point, both php and mysql are on the same server I have just tried localhost for HOST and I get the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Well, thats how I use it on a daily basis. If your username and password are correct, and if you're hosting the php and database in the same place, then localhost should work. Trying to think of any other problem that could be going on.

Comment: No changes with root. When I open phpmyadmin page it says Server: Localhost via UNIX socket and User: usernameforserver@localhost

Comment: Make sure the username/password is the same you use to access cpanel (and not some other you might be using for FTP, ie.) and also make sure the database name is complete. In some servers, they add a user prefix before the name. Ie. if your database is named "mydata" and your user in that server is "myuser" then its possible that in the server the database is named "myuser_mydata"

Comment: Btw: can you remove the -1 ? The answer is perfectly related to the post considering the code and the database are in the same server

Comment: Finally works, thanks a lot! I used password for cpanel and username for cpanel without @localhost. Thanks again for patience.

Answer (score 0):

It also seems that you swapped your constants, because some_db is not likely to be a user but rather a database. Try debugging and output the constants' values just before the 'mysql_connect' call. 
If this does not work, try debug_backtrace().

Comment: I think that it is not swapped. Maybe it takes for user just part of string because real username and database name follow the same pattern